# How to subclass a parent for mocking

Tags: java, unit-testing, design-patterns, mocking, refactoring

How do I subclass a parent class with a private constructor so that I can mock it?

I have refactored my code such that when it makes a call to a third party library, the calls are
wrapped so that I can mock the class and create a fake wrapper. I can then in theory return whatever I want
to test my production code using dependency injection etc.

For a few of the library calls, a single object instance is returned which in itself is a specific library
object type. In the production code, this then has subsequent calls made upon that object.

This is illustrated in the code below:

```
public class MyWrapper
{
  public LibraryObject MyWrappedCall()
  {
    LibraryObject x = ExternalLibrary.getLibObject();
    return x;
  }
}

public class MyProductionCode
{
  public void DoX()
  {
    LibraryObject lo = MyWrapper.getX();
    ProductionType pt = lo.doSomething();
  }
}
```

How do I fake the method doSomething() ? My first thought was instead of returning an instance object
from the wrapped call, return an object which is of the same type. So MyWrapper code could be enhanced 
as follows:

```
public class MyWrapper
{
  public LibraryObject MyWrappedCall()
  {
    //LibraryObject x = ExternalLibrary.getLibObject();
    MyMockLibraryObject mlo;
    return mlo;
  }

  public class MyMockLibraryObject extends LibraryObject
  {
    public ProductionType doSomething()
    {
      ProductionType pt;
      return pt;
    }
  }
}
```

The problem with this is that the parent class has a private constructor, so it cannot be subclassed.

Does anybody have any suggestions of how to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

sounds bad. You need to create a wrapper interface (and implementation) for hiding the LibraryObject type from your production code, so that you can mock the interface

Comment: I'm not so concerned that the LibraryObject type is in the production code since this is already in a Façade. All I want to do is return an object that I have control over so that I can choose what is returned to that object when calls are made.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to just mock whatever 3rd-party types you need to mock (but if possible, prefer an integration test with no mocking).

For Java, such mocking can be performed with the PowerMock or JMockit libraries, without having to create any wrappers. (Of course, if said wrappers bring other benefits, then you might prefer to keep them.) These mocking libraries don't operate by creating subclasses, so they are not constrained as those which do.